# Compiling Oracle OCI results in unknown type name 'varchar'

Tags: oracle, oracle-call-interface

I have a simple program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sqlda.h>
#include <sqlcpr.h>
#include <sql2oci.h>
#include <sqlca.h>
#include <oci.h>

#define UNAME_LEN 30
#define PWD_LEN 30

varchar username[UNAME_LEN]; 
varchar password[PWD_LEN]; 
varchar tnsname[32]; 

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  return 0;
}
```

when i try compiling it with mingw using gcc on windows 7 i am getting the following error

```
D:\oci>gcc -o ociclient.exe -I%ORACLE_HOME%\oci\include -I%ORACLE_HOME%\precomp\public ociclient2.c %ORACLE_HOME%\bin\oci.dll
**ociclient2.c:13:1: error: unknown type name 'varchar'
ociclient2.c:14:1: error: unknown type name 'varchar'
ociclient2.c:15:1: error: unknown type name 'varchar'**
```

Am i missing any includes or anything else

Answer (score 0):

A quick glance at [the OCI documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28395/oci03typ.htm#i423684) reveals the answer: it should be `varchar2`.