# Pro*c compliation error "unknown type name VARCHAR"

Tags: c, oracle, oracleclient, oracle-pro-c

Getting below "**error: unknown type name ‘VARCHAR’**" when compliing Proc*c code.

```
DEV >>:make
EIOO
CLEAN:
path/to/c/file/exe/xxxx
path/to/c/file/obj/xxxx.o
path/to/c/file/obj/yyyy.o
path/to/c/fileo/pc/yyyy.c
COMP: /path/to/c/file/xxxx.c
In file included from /path/to/c/file/xxxx.c:63:
/path/to/h/file/xxxx.c:54:8: **error: unknown type name ‘VARCHAR’
 static VARCHAR  evcRowid[21];**
        ^~~~~~~
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
make: *** [/src/billmill/make_include/mk_alku_vtuotanto:125: /path/to/c/file/xxxx.o] Error 1
virhekoodi 2
DEV >> :
```

My below are content of my pcscfg.cfg.

```
DEV >>:cat /usr/lib/oracle/19.10/client64/precomp/admin/pcscfg.cfg
sys_include=(/usr/include/oracle/19.10/client64,/usr/include,/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/include)
ltype=short
define=__x86_64__
define=_MATH_H

DEV >>:
```

/path/to/c/file/xxxx.c includes below all header files from Oracle DB client.

```
#include <oro.h> 
#include <oci.h>
#include <ociap.h>
#include <oraca.h>
#include <orid.h>
#include <ori.h>
#include <oratypes.h>
#include <ocidfn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sqlda.h>
#include <sqlcpr.h>
#include <sql2oci.h>
#include <sqlca.h>
```

I'm  using Oracle DB instant client 19.10. Referring [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407487/compiling-oracle-oci-results-in-unknown-type-name-varchar) I tried using VARCHAR2, still same error....

How can I get VARCHAR ad valid datatype for Proc*c code with Oracle DB instant client 19.10?
OS: RHEL-8 and gcc version 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-16) (GCC).

Comment: Please try to create a [mre] of your code that causes this error, and show it to us.

Comment: Did you preprocess your pro*c code with the proc preprocessor? –

Comment: (A side comment since it is like unrelated to your issue: upgrade.  Version 19.10 is a couple of years old.  The [current release](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html) is 19.19).

Comment: You didn't actually call precompiler `Pro*C`, you passed the precompiler-source to the C-compiler, which doesn't understand it. It should be something like this: `foo.pc --> [precompiler] --> foo.c --> [compiler] --> foo.o --> [linker] --> foo.exe`